# Python - Scaling one section of an array and not the rest

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to normalize a specific range of numbers in a data while keeping the rest the same value. This is a very large data set as well.

Here is my attempt,

```
import numpy as np

# An unrelated scaling measure, the intial array shape I want to keep.
Intscale1 = np.array([data/1700 for data in Int1])

# Normalizing the first 500 values in the array
Intscaled11 = 2*Intscale1[:500]

# Rest of the data set is left unchanged 
Intscaled12 = Intscale1[501:]

# Combing both to the same shape as Intscale1
Intscale111 = Intscaled11 += Intscaled12
```

This does not work unfortunately. It returns,

`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,) (1548,) (500,)`

for the last part.

Is their a way to do what I am wanting to accomplish?

Comment: Doesn't work is a vague description, tell sth more about what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use map. The problem I see is where you are using 2 * array. That action is actually like doing array + array which in python will just append the array after itself, so with a map you can fix it

```
# An unrelated scaling measure, the intial array shape I want to keep.
Intscale1 = np.array([data/1700 for data in Int1])

# Normalizing the first 500 values in the array
Intscaled11 = map(lambda x: x*2, Intscale1[:500])

# Rest of the data set is left unchanged 
Intscaled12 = Intscale1[501:]

# Combing both to the same shape as Intscale1
Intscale111 = np.concatenate([Intscaled1, Intscaled2])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `+` that you are trying to use works as an elementwise addition operator. It tries to add values from the arrays and fails, because they are of different size. The function concatenate from numpy lets you concatenate two numpy arrays into another, bigger one. If you had to rearrange the data, you can always use list comprehension and then convert result list into numpy array for faster and easier calculations. For your need, concatenate should work fine tough.

`Intscaled = np.concatenate([Intscaled11, Intscaled12)`

Comment: Thank you, but now it returns this `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,) (1547,) `

Comment: Yes, I reviewed my answer, should be correct right now,